# Winston logging to a file that begins with custom multi line text

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

Our Winston logging is already set up and working great using [winston-daily-rotate-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-daily-rotate-file) to create daily log files. What I now need to do is create those log files from a specific file template (or any other method) with a few header rows at the start of the file. We want to change our application to use a more stuctured logging for use with a separate internal app so our support team can easier traverse large log files.

Normally the log files append each log into the file, starting with a blank file. To specify, I want that file to begin with a few lines of text before any logging is added.

Is this possible? I can't find any reference to functionality like this in either Winston or winston-daily-rotate-file. Perhaps I'm meant to create hook into the file stream using the `options` object parameter?

Comment: I already tried the transport.on('new',....) approach, what I found was that the lines at the beginning of the file are overwriting the logs for a couple of lines, perhaps because of the async nature of the two functions. I was rotating csv files and was trying to add a header.
`const addHeaderRow = (newFilename) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const headers = ['col1', 'col2']
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(newFilename) ;
    const data = '${headers.join(',')}\n'
    ws.write(data)
    resolve()
  })
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling the `rotate` event is the way to go.
In the following code, I am rotating every 2 files every minute for demo purposes. I am appending text on top of each new file, and also every rotation. As rotation happens later, you see ROTATE above NEW, which is expected. For your scenario I don't think you need the `new` event.
**Demo**

```javascript
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const fs = require('fs');

var transport = new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
    frequency: '1m',
    filename: 'log-%DATE%',
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm',
    zippedArchive: false,
    maxSize: '1k',
    maxFiles: '2',
    extension: 'log'
});

transport.on('rotate', function (oldFilename, newFilename) {
    console.log("rotate");

    var data = fs.readFileSync(newFilename); //read existing contents into data
    var fd = fs.openSync(newFilename, 'w+');
    var buffer = Buffer.from('ROTATE text inserted on top \n');
    fs.writeSync(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, 0); //write new data
    fs.writeSync(fd, data, 0, data.length, buffer.length); //append old data
    fs.close(fd);
});

transport.on('new', function (newFilename) {
    console.log("new");

    var data = fs.readFileSync(newFilename); //read existing contents into data
    var fd = fs.openSync(newFilename, 'w+');
    var buffer = Buffer.from('NEW text inserted on top \n');
    fs.writeSync(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, 0); //write new data
    fs.writeSync(fd, data, 0, data.length, buffer.length); //append old data
    fs.close(fd);
});

var logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        transport
    ]
});

async function demo() {
    for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        logger.info('Hello World ' + i);
        console.log(i);
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    }
}

demo();
```

**Console output**

```
1
2
3
new
rotate
4
5
6
7
8
9
new
rotate
10
11
12
13
14
15
new
rotate
16
17
18
19
```

**Files created**

```
log-2022-06-13-14-36log
log-2022-06-13-14-37log
```

**Files content**

1:

```
ROTATE text inserted on top 
NEW text inserted on top 
{"level":"info","message":"Hello World 10"}
{"level":"info","message":"Hello World 11"}
{"level":"info","message":"Hello World 12"}
{"level":"info","message":"Hello World 13"}
{"level":"info","message":"Hello World 14"}
{"level":"info","message":"Hello World 15"}
```

2:

```
ROTATE text inserted on top 
NEW text inserted on top 
{"level":"info","message":"Hello World 16"}
{"level":"info","message":"Hello World 17"}
{"level":"info","message":"Hello World 18"}
{"level":"info","message":"Hello World 19"}
```

Comment: My bounty timed out 38 minutes ago when I didn't know this had an answer, I'm sorry :( This does look like it will work. I'll try it shortly.

Comment: @matt123miller No worries :) please consider accepting the answer (if it answers your question/solves your issue).

Comment: Confirmed it all works as expected! This will be a huge help for our support team. Thank you.

Comment: @evilmandarine thanks, do you know of a solution which does not utilize "fs" but can make use of a transport function directly, like transport.write("Header")

Comment: @SuryaSrivastava your comment would deserve a new question but basically there is no such method on transports. The `_write` method is on the TransportStream class which is the base class for all transports, including the one used above ([DailyRotateFile](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file)). I am using `fs` to handle what the OP asked, which is adding custom text on top of the new file as soon as there is a rotation. The logger "requests" a log creation then the transport "decides" how/where to write it.